# Data processing stratgy kafka or database or any other persistance

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, architecture, software-design

I am working on a large amount of (asynchronous)data processing strategy , i am oversimplifying the problem here -

I get a record set - let's say -

```
A-event1
B-event1 
B-event2  
C-event1
C-event2
C-event3
B-event3
A-event2
A-event3
D-event1
D-event2
C-event4
A-event4
A-event4
A-event6
A-eventfinal
B-eventfinal
C-event6
C-event7
C-eventFinal
D-eventFinal
```

Conversion of this record set would be

```
A-event1      B-event1         C-event1        D-event1
A-event2      B-event2         C-event2        D-event2
A-event3      B-event3         C-event3        D-eventFinal
A-event4      B-eventfinal     C-event4
A-eventFinal                   C-event5
                               C-event6
                               C-event7  
                               C-eventFinal
```

Once I get the final event data then only this set is ready for further processing.Once Entity hits the final, it is eligible for further processing.This individual set is now being sent to a third party application, which it gets processed and upon it successful completion, it will return a closure event or acknowledgement or may be failure, Therefore, this individual set is ready to get purged or remain for further correction(in case of failure),caveat to this, the acknowledgement or closure might not get received for days. so i have to persist this data somewhere(maybe database, Kafka or some sort of equivalent)

Here A, B C and D i am using as Entity Identifier, this could be in tens of thousand(like guid).I also needed a capability to reprocess this entire record set.

Few options that i have elaborated are

1. Have a dynamic Kafka topic for each identifier, but any point it might be maintaining 10 of thousand topics, I am trying to avoid DB.
2. Have put an entire set a one Kafka topic and create another retry topic, kind of application X keep polling retry topic.

I am open for any data processing algorithm here, not to mentioned data loss is not acceptable.

I understand this explanation is little abstract, please do let me know, if you need further explanation, Any help or suggestion will greatly appreciated.

I am looking a architecture approach.

Comment: The first question you need to answer is the time to do the post processing after you receive the final event.  This will tell if you can save data into a file or you have to same the data in memory.  You have to determine the speed verses memory and the amount of memory in machine verses amount of memory need to perform the algorithm.  Then determine the algorithm.

Comment: Is it safe to assume, the structure of all events are the same, they have an id, the closure comes back with an id?

Comment: yes and yes. That’s correct. Id is unique for each set, that’s how it would recorded as audit trail for an application.

Comment: @jdweng Post processing is not a time sensitive but accuracy based.

Comment: Then what about memory?

Comment: Application does not really have to memory optimized per se however, it should not be taking entire server down. I can not keep everything in memory, This application to nr built fault tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a little light on the details. However, you could easily solve this with a database, and some sort of pipeline (choose your poison)

In this extremely contrived example I have used Dataflow, you could use any structure or framework you like, however the problems are still the same. In the example Dataflow has some things it can do fairly effortlessly.

- Can use the async and await pattern.
- Processes things in an orderly fashion (or not)
- Can use queues to process, can process things in parallel
- Configure max degrees of parallelism
- Can create perpetual pipelines
- Can cancellation tokens and much more

I had to make a lot of assumptions and left a lot to the imagination.

- You would need to consider fault tolerance
- Implement a cancellation regime
- Adjust your parallelism and other options
- Implement a database for the events
- and have a fall-over and restart mechanism if your process goes down

**Example**

```
public enum EventType
{
   Event,
   Final,
   Finished,
   Error
}

public class EventMessage
{
   public int GroupId { get; set; }
   public int EventId { get; set; }
   public string Payload { get; set; }
   public EventType EventType { get; set; }
}

public static ConcurrentDictionary<int,List<EventMessage>> _dataStore = new ConcurrentDictionary<int,List<EventMessage>>();
private static BufferBlock<EventMessage> _start;
private static ActionBlock<EventMessage> _persistBlock;
private static ActionBlock<EventMessage> _processBlock;
private static ActionBlock<EventMessage> _finalizeBlock;
private static TransformBlock<EventMessage, EventMessage> _reprocessBlock;
private static TransformBlock<EventMessage, EventMessage> _queue;
private static Random _r = new Random();


static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

   // this is just a buffer that can receive asynchronous events
   _start = new BufferBlock<EventMessage> (new DataflowBlockOptions(){EnsureOrdered = true});

   // we need an orderly queue, the bounded capacity is 1 so we can process events in order 
   // ie so you don't process the final before all events are recevied
   _queue = new TransformBlock<EventMessage, EventMessage>(message => message, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions(){BoundedCapacity = 1});

   // save your events to the database
   _persistBlock = new ActionBlock<EventMessage>(PersistAction, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 1 });

   // process the final event
   _processBlock = new ActionBlock<EventMessage>(ProcessAction);

   // process the event from the 3rd party service
   _finalizeBlock = new ActionBlock<EventMessage>(FinalizeAction);

   // reprocess on failure or whatever you need to do
   _reprocessBlock = new TransformBlock<EventMessage, EventMessage>(Reprocess);

   // link it all together
   _start.LinkTo(_queue);
   _queue.LinkTo(_persistBlock, (x) => x.EventType == EventType.Event);
   _queue.LinkTo(_processBlock, (x) => x.EventType == EventType.Final);
   _queue.LinkTo(_finalizeBlock, (x) => x.EventType == EventType.Finished);
   _queue.LinkTo(_reprocessBlock, (x) => x.EventType == EventType.Error);
   _reprocessBlock.LinkTo(_start);

   // create some events
   var tasks= Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(CreateEvents);

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

   Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async Task CreateEvents(int groupId)
{
   var events = Enumerable
      .Range(1, _r.Next(2, 5))
      .Select(x => new EventMessage()
      {
         GroupId = groupId,
         EventId = x,
         EventType = EventType.Event
      });
   foreach (var e in events)
   {
      await Task.Delay(_r.Next(10, 100));
      await _start.SendAsync(e);
   }

   await _start.SendAsync(new EventMessage()
   {
      GroupId = groupId,
      Payload = $"Final Event",
      EventType = EventType.Final
   });
}
private static EventMessage Reprocess(EventMessage e)
{
   // the event come back as an error, so we push it back on the the queue
   Console.WriteLine($"Reprocessing group : {e.GroupId}");
   e.EventType = EventType.Final;
   e.Payload = e.Payload + " Error";
   return e;
}

private static async Task PersistAction(EventMessage e)
{
   // this is simulating saving the event to a db
   Console.WriteLine($"Saving event : {e.GroupId}:{e.EventId}");
   await Task.Delay(_r.Next(10, 100));
   _dataStore.AddOrUpdate(e.GroupId,
      (x) => new List<EventMessage>() {e},
      (x, l) =>
      {
         l.Add(e);
         return l;
      });
}
private static async Task ProcessAction(EventMessage e)
{
   // this is simulating reading all the events for that group from the db
   // and sending to your 3rd service
   Console.WriteLine($"Sending to service : {e.GroupId}");

   await Task.Delay(_r.Next(10, 100));

   // this is simulating receiving a result from the 3rd party service 
   // just pushes the event back in to the queue, to be finialised or reprocessed
   // choose randomly if it was a success or failure
   // obviously this would be called by something else, possibly your message queue
   if (_r.Next(0, 2) == 0)
      e.EventType = EventType.Finished;
   else
      e.EventType = EventType.Error;


   Console.WriteLine($"Service returned : {e.GroupId}, {e.EventType}");

   await _start.SendAsync(e);
}
private static void FinalizeAction(EventMessage e)
{
 // pruge the records, we are all done
   _dataStore.TryRemove(e.GroupId, out var l);

   Console.WriteLine($"*** Finalize : {e.GroupId} - {string.Join(",", l.Select(x => x.EventId))}");
}
```

**Output**

```
Saving event : 4:1
Saving event : 1:1
Saving event : 4:2
Saving event : 1:2
Saving event : 5:1
Saving event : 5:2
Saving event : 3:1
Saving event : 2:1
Saving event : 1:3
Saving event : 5:3
Sending to service : 1
Saving event : 5:4
Service returned : 1, Error
Sending to service : 5
Saving event : 2:2
Service returned : 5, Error
Saving event : 3:2
Saving event : 4:3
Saving event : 4:4
Sending to service : 4
Saving event : 2:3
Service returned : 4, Error
Saving event : 3:3
Sending to service : 3
Saving event : 2:4
Reprocessing group : 1
Reprocessing group : 5
Reprocessing group : 4
Service returned : 3, Error
Sending to service : 2
Reprocessing group : 3
Service returned : 2, Finished
Sending to service : 1
*** Finalize : 2 - 1,2,3,4
Service returned : 1, Finished
Sending to service : 5
*** Finalize : 1 - 1,2,3
Service returned : 5, Finished
Sending to service : 4
*** Finalize : 5 - 1,2,3,4
Service returned : 4, Finished
Sending to service : 3
*** Finalize  : 4 - 1,2,3,4
Service returned : 3, Error
Reprocessing group : 3
Sending to service : 3
Service returned : 3, Finished
*** Finalize : 3 - 1,2,3
```

Note: this is just an example, it's not meant to be a complete solution or a recommendation for dataflow, or even how you should solve it. It's merely just to give you an idea of a structured pipeline.